# How to share one folder content between two docker container and allow one of them to delete and write to the shared folder?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am creating a dev environment for ionic/Angluar project with docker. Where Nodejs is the image for watching and building `www` files from src code on the host machine (local src code) (with `ng build --watch --poll=2000`) and NGINX image shall get those generated `www` folder.

I have tried two approaches for this use case and both failed:

- Approach number 1: I have bind mounted the folder to both containers: The problem here was that NGINX container were not able to sync/get the file from `www` on the host. Although, NodeJS container manages to generate files and sync with host directory `www`. Reason is: NGINX looses the bind mount when NODEJS deletes and regenerates the `www` directory.
- Approach number 2: I have used data volumes: But NodeJS container fails on start because it cannot delete this `www` file in order to regenerate with new `www` sub-files (because it is locked by NGINX).
  Error message:

```
frontend        | EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rmdir '/home/frontend/www'
frontend        | Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rmdir '/home/frontend/www'
frontend        |     at Object.rmdirSync (fs.js:752:3)
...
```

Compose file looks as follows: (I marked the above mentioned approaches in the compose-file, but of course I use them once at a time)

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  web-server:
    image: webserver-nginx:latest
    container_name: webserver
    build:
      context: ../nginx/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-nginx    
    ports:
    - "80:80"
    volumes:
    - /my_host_machine/www:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro # approach number 1
    - www:/usr/share/nginx/html/afv:ro # approach number 2
    depends_on:
      - frontend

  frontend:
    image: frontend-angular:latest
    container_name: frontend
    build:
      context: /foo/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-nodejs-frontend
    volumes:
      - /my_host_machine/www:/home/frontend/www # approach number 1
      - www:/home/frontend/www # approach number 2

volumes:
  www:
```

Could anyone help me or has a suggestion or a workaround?

Comment: You need to use some kind of symlink. like we do with single file in different folders

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This would be basically like doing a bind mount. So because the other container will delete then recreate the file, the first container will lose the sym-link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the problem was as following:

I used approach #1

This problem only happens at the initializing point, where NODEJS removed the `www` folder after NGINX has maintained a bind mount to it. 
Restarting NGINX container, after NODEJS has finished generating `www` folder and files, will solve the problem, even if NODEJS regenerates the web files afterwards (because it will not remove the complete folder again).

Instead of restarting NGINX manually each time, I used a HealthCheck and an autoheal container. (Note that if you are using swarm you won't need the autoheal container)

Here is how I did it:

Create `healthcheck.sh` where the Dockerfile is:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z "$(ls -A /path/to/mounted/file/in/NGINX/container)" ]; then exit 1; else exit 0; fi
```

add those lines to NGINX Dockerfile:

```
COPY healthcheck.sh .

HEALTHCHECK --interval=3s --retries=10 CMD sh /healthcheck.sh
```

add those lines to docker-compose.yml:

```
autoheal:
image: willfarrell/autoheal
volumes:
- /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
environment:
  AUTOHEAL_CONTAINER_LABEL: all
restart: always
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your first option is almost workable. Try taking that bind mounted directory and making subdirectories within it for `www` and another for the source code. Have one container build from the source directory and move the result to the `www` directory where it gets picked up by the other container (without deleting the entire directory).